# `sed` updates the meta dates of all accessed files

Tags: text-processing, sed

I used `sed -i 's/oldpat/newpat/g' ~/mydir/**/*.txt` to replace some str in some text files.

However, the modified dates of all files, including those with contents unchanged, were changed to current date by `sed` and I lost their time info.

Is there anyway to avoid the update of file dates when using `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, looks like that `sed`, with the `-i` switch, *always* creates a temporary file (emphasis mine):

> `-i[SUFFIX]`
>   `--in-place[=SUFFIX]`
>
> This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU
>   `sed' does this by **creating a temporary file and sending output to
>   this file** rather than to the standard output.(1).
>
> This option implies `-s`.
>
> When the end of the file is reached, **the temporary file is renamed
>   to the output file's original name**. The extension, if supplied,
>   is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
>   temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2)).

It means that even if the file contents will not be changed by `sed`, the original file gets recreated.

A workaround would be to use a script which uses `grep` to find if the file needs the substitution before using `sed`.

A simple example:

```
for FILE in ~/mydir/**/*.txt 
do
    if grep -q PATTERN "$FILE"; then
         sed -i 's/oldpat/newpat/g' "$FILE"
    fi
done
```

The `-q` switch to `grep` it's used to prevent it to output the matching line to `stdout`.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. I didn't know there is usage like `if grep -q PATTERN "$FILE"`. The `-i` behavior of `sed` is damned. I worked under `dropbox` folder and now 20,000+ files still in indexing and uploading.........